# Por que Tentativa de leitura ou gravação em memória protegida.?

Tags: vb.net

O que eu estou a fazer é pegar um frame de alguns vídeos, mas sempre que tento acessar as imagens salvas eu recebo *Tentativa de leitura ou gravação em memória protegida*. Eu não consigo usar eles depois de "salvar". O que eu to fazendo de errado?

```
Imports System.Drawing   
Imports System.Windows.Forms  
Imports Emgu.CV

    Private Const LocFrame = 0.2
    Public Shared listMiniatura As New ImageList With {.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit, .ImageSize = New Size(255, 255)}        

    Public Shared Sub GetThumbnail(path As String)
            If listMiniatura.Images.ContainsKey(path) Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim f As Integer
            Dim m As Mat

            'Abre o video para pegar o frame
            Using cap As New VideoCapture(path)
                If cap.IsOpened Then

                    'Posição do frame que será retirado
                    f = cap.GetCaptureProperty(CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount) * LocFrame
                    cap.SetCaptureProperty(CvEnum.CapProp.PosFrames, f)
                    m = New Mat
                    cap.Read(m)

                    'Salva em listMiniatura
                    listMiniatura.Images.Add(path, m.Bitmap)                    
                End If
            End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Provavelmente está tentando usar paralelismo sem entender como funciona, e provavelmente não precisa disso. Eu evitaria com todas as forças fazer algo assim, até não ter outra forma, mas como parece IO, deve ter solução melhor.

Comment: Já tentei sem, da a mesma coisa.

Comment: Quando vou usar a imagem que está em listMiniatura com ou sem paralelismo da o mesmo erro.